# How to get a macro to expand in Cython

Tags: cython

I have a C header which defines a function in a macro.  I need to call it from Cython.  Is there a way to use the macro in Cython and have it fully expanded?  I already have the arguments as C types.

I've tried using cdef like I would for a function, which is, I think, what the documentation says.

Comment: always show the code you tried

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#define SUM(a,b) (a) + (b)
```

In this case, declare it as a function in a `cdef extern from "lib.h"` block, and specify the type of arguments it takes and should return. Refer to the [docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html).

Comment: What about type generic macros in C11, with `_Generic`? Cython fused types only offers a very limited subset of what `_Generic` is used for.

Comment: i need this kind of macro but seems no such thing in cython: `#define bool3 int`

Comment: @Dee May you could use a typedef instead, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73384834/how-to-use-a-type-macro-from-a-c-header/73384835#73384835)