# How to use a type macro from a c header?

Tags: cython

In an external library is a macro to a type:

```
typedef TCHAR MY_TYPE;
#define MY_MACRO_TYPE MY_TYPE;
```

At any place in the library the macro is used instead of the type.

So how can I provide this macro for cython (`cdef extern MY_MACRO_TYPE variable`)?

I tried to use it like it is:

```
cdef extern from "my_lib.h":
    ctypedef TCHAR MY_TYPE
    cdef MY_MACRO_TYPE MY_TYPE
```

Which throws the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    ctypedef TCHAR MY_TYPE
    cdef MY_MACRO_TYPE MY_TYPE
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

src/pytypes.pxd:22:9: 'MY_MACRO_TYPE' is not a type identifier
warning: src/pytypes.pxd:22:22: 'MY_TYPE' redeclared
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wrote this question, I found a possible solution, which may help anyone else.

Cause cython just needs to know the type, you can ignore the macro and use a typedef alias instead.

So it looks like:

```
cdef extern from "my_lib.h":
    ctypedef TCHAR MY_TYPE
    ctypedef MY_TYPE MY_MACRO_TYPE
```

Which works for me, without any errors.